# Identify when time series passes through threshold both in graph and table

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series

I have a time series that's comparing the "Actual" to the "Predicted" channel values. (This is for a predictive maintenance application of a machine)

Since I'm training the model when the machine is brand new, I'm interested in the times that the comparison between those channels passes a specific threshold.

Ideally I'd like to be able to identify these events both in a graph and in a table.

Below are a few sample rows of data and what I was trying to do with the graph.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Data format:

```
Index          Time         Actual  Predicted   Score
  1      6/10/2020 0:00      134       124       8.1%
  2      6/10/2020 1:00      135       127       6.3%
  3      6/10/2020 2:00      129       125       3.2%
  4      6/10/2020 3:00      134       130       3.1%
  5      6/10/2020 4:00      131       127       3.1%
  6      6/10/2020 5:00      134       127       5.5%
  7      6/10/2020 6:00      129       125       3.2%
  8      6/10/2020 7:00      130       133      -2.3%
  9      6/10/2020 8:00      133       138      -3.6%
 10      6/10/2020 9:00      125       129      -3.1%
 11      6/10/2020 10:00     125       131      -4.6%
 12      6/10/2020 11:00     126       136      -7.4%
 13      6/10/2020 12:00     128       136      -5.9%
 14      6/10/2020 13:00     133       138      -3.6%
 15      6/10/2020 14:00     134       130       3.1%
 16      6/10/2020 15:00     129       125       3.2%
 17      6/10/2020 16:00     129       125       3.2%
```

So in this particular case I'd be looking to have a table where I can detect the times that it went below a specific threshold and back up above it. For example -4.0.

```
ID    EventType        EventTime
11       Red        6/10/2020 10:00
14      Green       6/10/2020 13:00
```

And then, ideally, I'd want to be able to also highlight such events on a graph.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly different computation for the changes.  The basic steps are:

1. Convert the scores to `float` (remove the percent)
2. Label all the scores below the cutoff of -4 (with 1, else 0).
3. Take a `diff()` on the relabeled scores
4. Replace those `diff()` values based on the color you want to assign.

I broke these steps out into different columns, but you don't need to do so if you want to not add junk to your `df`:

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].str.replace('%','').astype(float)
df['Below_Cutoff'] = np.where(df['Score'] <= -4, 1, 0)
df["Changes"] = df['Below_Cutoff'].diff()
df['Change_Colors'] = df['Changes'].map({1:'Red', -1:'Green', 0:np.nan})
```

Result:

```
                 Time  Actual  Predicted  ...  Below_Cutoff  Changes  Change_Colors
1  2020-06-10 00:00:00     134        124  ...             0      NaN            NaN
2  2020-06-10 01:00:00     135        127  ...             0      0.0            NaN
3  2020-06-10 02:00:00     129        125  ...             0      0.0            NaN
4  2020-06-10 03:00:00     134        130  ...             0      0.0            NaN
5  2020-06-10 04:00:00     131        127  ...             0      0.0            NaN
6  2020-06-10 05:00:00     134        127  ...             0      0.0            NaN
7  2020-06-10 06:00:00     129        125  ...             0      0.0            NaN
8  2020-06-10 07:00:00     130        133  ...             0      0.0            NaN
9  2020-06-10 08:00:00     133        138  ...             0      0.0            NaN
10 2020-06-10 09:00:00     125        129  ...             0      0.0            NaN
11 2020-06-10 10:00:00     125        131  ...             1      1.0            Red
12 2020-06-10 11:00:00     126        136  ...             1      0.0            NaN
13 2020-06-10 12:00:00     128        136  ...             1      0.0            NaN
14 2020-06-10 13:00:00     133        138  ...             0     -1.0          Green
15 2020-06-10 14:00:00     134        130  ...             0      0.0            NaN
16 2020-06-10 15:00:00     129        125  ...             0      0.0            NaN
17 2020-06-10 16:00:00     129        125  ...             0      0.0            NaN
```

**Note** that in the above, the first entry of the `diff()` is always be NaN; I think this is not a problem if you only want to detect the threshold crossings.  But say if the first value was below -4 and you wanted a red point there, this would fail.

So to get a table with only the cutoffs, you can do:

```
only_changes = df[~pd.isna(df['Change_Colors'])]
```

And to plot, you can do (this is similar to Andrea's answer, but specific to my example):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,3.5))

ax.plot(df['Time'], df['Score'])
ax.scatter(only_changes['Time'], only_changes['Score'], c=only_changes['Change_Colors'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator([0,4,8,12,16,20,24]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.hlines(-4, min(df['Time']), max(df['Time']), colors = 'r')
```

[image]

---

### Labeling the actual crossing

Additionally, if you want to interpolate to estimate the label the actual threshold crossing, you can create higher frequency timestamps to interpolate:

```
minutes = pd.date_range(df['Time'].min(), df['Time'].max(), freq='1T')

interp = pd.Series(np.interp(minutes, df['Time'], df['Score']))
interp.index = minutes
only_changes = pd.Series(np.where(interp <= -4, 1, 0)).diff().map({1:'Red', -1:'Green', 0:np.nan})

only_changes = only_changes[~pd.isna(only_changes)]
```

And then replace the `scatter` call for the same plotting code above with:

```
ax.scatter(interp.index[only_changes.index], interp[only_changes.index], c=only_changes)
```

[image]

**But note that now the red/green points are not placed at real measured points from your data!**

Comment: For sure your solution is more efficient than mine :-) only one thing: if the first value is below the threshold, it seems to me that your code does not catch it, right?

Comment: Thank you very much for this, your solution was actually super smart, to use that mask and then calculate the diff throughout it is such an efficient way to do it. I had been scratching my head for a while and you hit the nail on the head. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the most efficient way; however, you can iterate over rows and check in which row the `'Score'` becomes lower or greater than the threshold with respect to the previous row. You can save the result in another column and use this to filter and plot your data.
For the sake of simplicity, I saved the sample of the data you provided in a `data.csv` file, where the `'Score'` column is `float`, i. e. I removed the `%` character and saved only the numerical value as `float`.
Check the code below:

```
# import
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data and set threshold
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
threshold = -4

# catch the rows where 'Score' crosses the threshold
df['EventType'] = ''

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if (index  - 1 == 0) and (df['Score'].iloc[index - 1] < threshold):
        df['EventType'].iloc[index] = 'Green'
        continue

    if (df['Score'].iloc[index - 1] < threshold) and (df['Score'].iloc[index - 2] > threshold):
        df['EventType'].iloc[index - 1] = 'Red'

    if (df['Score'].iloc[index - 1] > threshold) and (df['Score'].iloc[index - 2] < threshold):
        df['EventType'].iloc[index - 1] = 'Green'

# print results
print(df[df['EventType'] != ''])

# plot the trend
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 6))

ax.plot(df['Time'],
        df['Score'])

# plot the catched results
for color in ['Green', 'Red']:
    ax.scatter(x = df[df['EventType'] == color]['Time'],
               y = df[df['EventType'] == color]['Score'],
               marker = 'o',
               s = 100,
               facecolor = color,
               edgecolor = 'black')

# plot the threshold
ax.hlines(y = threshold, xmin = df['Time'].iloc[0], xmax = df['Time'].iloc[-1], colors = 'r')

plt.show()
```

which gives me this output:

```
        Index   Time  Actual  Predicted  Score EventType
11  6/10/2020  10:00     125        131   -4.6       Red
14  6/10/2020  13:00     133        138   -3.6     Green
```

and this plot:

[image]

As you can see, it catches:

- the first row where the `'Score'` becomes lower than the threshold, with respect to the previous row, and mark this row in `'Red'`
- the first row where the `'Score'` return greater than the threshold, with respect to the previous row, and mark this row in `'Green'`